# a4 size div zoom in and zoom out content view issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am using a parent div and inside that parent div , i am using a a4-div with a4 size dimensions , i want zoom in zoom out for a4-div , zoom in and zoom out is working fine but if i click zoom in (zoom: 0.5/0.6/0.7), i am unable to see the text it is hiding. i am attaching the code below , can anyone please help me . below are the screenshots [image]

Thanks in advance

```js
    let scale = 0.4; // Initial scale
    const a4Div = document.getElementById('a4-div');

    function zoomIn() {
        if (scale < 2) { // Limiting to maximum scale of 2
            scale += 0.1;
            updateScale();
        }
    }

    function zoomOut() {
        if (scale > 0.4) { // Limiting to minimum scale of 0.4
            scale -= 0.1;
            updateScale();
        }
    }

    function updateScale() {
        a4Div.style.zoom = scale;

        // Calculate top margin to keep the content centered vertically
        const parentHeight = document.querySelector('.parent').clientHeight;
        const a4Height = a4Div.clientHeight * scale;
        const marginTop = Math.max(0, (parentHeight - a4Height) / 2);
        a4Div.style.marginTop = marginTop + 'px';
    }
```

```css
body, html {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .parent {
        height: calc(100vh - 200px); /* Adjust as needed */
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: lightgray;
        overflow: auto; /* Enable scrolling within the parent div */
    }

    .a4-div {
        width: 210mm; /* A4 width */
        height: 297mm; /* A4 height */
        background-color: white;
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin: 10px; /* Adjust margin as needed */
        zoom: 0.4; /* Default zoom level */
        transition: zoom 0.3s ease; /* Add smooth transition for zoom effect */
    }

    .zoom-buttons {
        position: fixed;
        top: 20px;
        right: 20px;
    }

    .zoom-btn {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="a4-div" id="a4-div">
        <!-- Your content goes here -->
        This is your A4-sized div. Adjust the content as needed.
    </div>
</div>

<div class="zoom-buttons">
    <button class="zoom-btn" onclick="zoomIn()">Zoom In</button>
    <button class="zoom-btn" onclick="zoomOut()">Zoom Out</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Although I cannot clearly see, if this helps your problem, I want to tell you about the beauty of A4. It has the **Lichtenberg Ratio** 1:root of 2. Even if you halve it, it stays the same ratio. It is also called the **Japanese Proportion**, and has something to do with the [**Silver Ratio**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_ratio). 

Comment: Why do you have a `height` on `.parent`?

Comment: thanks for your quick reply , iam using parent div height as height: calc(100vh - 200px);

Comment: Why? Because without the line, the text is showing. 

Comment: i cant , get you , can you explain me, what i did the mistake?

Comment: When you leave the `.parent` to `height: auto` it shows the whole A4: https://jsfiddle.net/TRNCFRMCN/xk7v1ntw/2/ .